# dynamic library vs static library at runtime

Tags: c++, dynamic-linking

If I have a project, where I have two modules `A` and `B`, and they both link with a third library `C`.

Is it true that if `C` is a static library, then the calls made to `C` from `A` and `B` each maintain a separate state of `C`? Do they have different heaps?

On the other hand, if `C` is a shared library, then `A` and `B` would have access to a shared state of `C`?

p.s. the application entry point is in `A` or `B`.

Comment: It very much depends on your OS. Windows DLLs work very differently from \*nix shared objects, and there's no one single mode of work for all flavors of \*nix and methods of linking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your OS, and the options you use to compile and
link.  Under Unix, by default, all common symbols in two or more
shared libraries will resolve to the names in the first library
loaded; for most Unices, this applies to names in the main as
well (but the GNU linker used in Linux requires a special option
for this).  Under Windows, it's a bit trickier; each statically
linked library will have its own copy of the state, and there's
no easy work-around, other than creating a third DLL to wrap the
static library, and only accessing it through symbols in that
DLL.

Comment: I'm on OS X 10.8 with xcode 5 and compiling with system provided clang. Where may I find reference on the flags required to resolve common symbols to the same name?

Comment: **Use a dynamic library**. Getting it to work with static linking involves unneeded hackery. Don't.

Comment: In the compiler/linker documentation.  But isn't OS X just a dialect of Unix.  If so, there should be no problem.

Comment: @n.m. Actually, it's usually simpler and preferable to use static libraries for everything but the system interfaces and plugins.

Comment: @JamesKanze If you have global state, you only should have one copy of the state, and one module owning it. A static library can own nothing. It is a non-entity as far as execution is concerned. A loadable binary (exe or dynamic lib) is. So a dynamic library must be a unique owner of the state. Never having any global state is better still, but it's another issue.

Comment: @n.m. An object owns state, not a library.  In general, dynamic linking just offers an additional source of errors.  It should be avoided except in the cases where it brings some concrete advantage.

Comment: @JamesKanze I'm not sure I understand you. Anyway, dynamic libraries are a fact of life. Most things are built out of plugins. Software I work with is 90% plugins. It is static linking that is an additional source of errors for me. Actually it's the mixing of the two methods. Since we have dynamic linking anyway and this is not going to change any time soon, it makes sense to link everything dynamically.

Comment: @n.m. It depends on the application domain.  If you're writing plug-ins, then obviously, you need dynamic libraries.  If you're writing applications, with your own executable, you only want them for things like system libraries; you want the executable to be as monolithic as possible, in order to avoid DLL-hell.

Comment: @n.m. Actually, you may want static linking with plugins as well.  Because you typically want each plug-in to be completely autonomous, with no accidentally shared state with other plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Static linking versus dynamic linking does not make a difference to the state management of the linked library from the point of view of your application. The library has a single state and all dependent modules are subject to it.

Where I think you are getting confused is in the optimizations that static linking versus dynamic linking allow for the operating system. A dynamic library can be loaded into memory once and mapped differently for each process that uses it. This eliminates the need to load in exact copies of pages that are already loaded.

Comment: Hmm okay. It's weird because in my application I ran into a problem where the state accessed from module B is okay, but if I try to access them from module A, then it becomes corrupted.

Comment: And someone suggested me building C as a shared library instead of a static one.

Comment: os x 10.8, and yes it's multi-threaded. the module A I was referring to was an existing project that I'm porting to mac, module B was the CEF1(chromium embedded framework), and C is v8.

Comment: Sorry. I got nothin'.

Comment: that's alright :) Thanks for the information though.